# Centroid of a cosine shaped rod

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, engineering

There's a problem in Hibbeler's 14th edition of Statics for Engineering that I've tried a few times and couldn't solve. The problem is shown below. It wants me to find the centroid coordinates of a cosine shaped rod.

I've seen many examples not only in the book but also on the internet and couldn't find any similar solution.

BTW, the solutions we usually find on the internet don't include this problem.

I'd be glad if you could help me; this is driving me crazy.

[image]

Comment: Does this have anything to do with the Mathematica software application or Wolfram programming language? Perhaps you are on the wrong site.

Comment: Actually you can find this in an engineering book. The problem wants you to find the coordinates in function of "a". Roman's answer below gives (0.29, 0.53), it's correct tho.

Answer (score 2):

Let's do this for $a=1$; the centroid coordinates will be proportional to $a$.

```
y[x_] = Cos[π*x];
```

length of the curve:

```
L = Integrate[Sqrt[1 + (y'[x])^2], {x, 0, 1/2}]
```

> EllipticE[-π^2]/π

$x$-coordinate of the centroid: numerical integration because analytic integral doesn't evaluate

```
X = NIntegrate[x*Sqrt[1 + (y'[x])^2], {x, 0, 1/2}]/L
```

> 0.298801

$y$-coordinate of the centroid:

```
Y = Integrate[y[x]*Sqrt[1 + (y'[x])^2], {x, 0, 1/2}]/L
```

> (π Sqrt[1 + π^2] + ArcSinh[π])/(2 π EllipticE[-π^2])

numerical values of the centroid coordinates:

```
{X, Y} // N
```

> {0.298801, 0.537174}

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!